# Codeigniter redirect non-www to www preventing form submission

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

Issue with Codeigniter redirection in .HTACCESS file. My redirection code is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domainname\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domainname.net/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This seems to work correctly but i noticed that forms submission stopped working because of the redirection. Any ideas please?

Comment: Why do you have the rewrite condition? Do you have the entire `.htaccess` file to show? Remember that you only need a series of lines to get it working out-of-the-box: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, and
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`.

Comment: @Dykotomee So that i can redirect non www to www. I have added the remaining part of the .htaccess.

Comment: any one out there who has done this help?

Comment: Are you submitting forms via `POST` or `GET`? Also, in your original comment you mentioned that something "stopped working" – can you edit your question to include the original `.htaccess` file where it previously _was_ working?

Comment: I am submitting it as POST. I will update the question with the original file soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#Redirect to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```